# Create Page URL using database & Node

Tags: express

im trying to create pages via req.parmas with diffrent deatails in data.js

I've tried this

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { persons } = require("./persons");
//Links
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
      <h1>Welcome to the site a.a.a.malon </h1>
      <a href="/employee/Holland">oved 1</a><br> 
          <!-- 1 -->
          <a href="/employee/37">oved 2</a><br>//NOT WORKING
    `);
});

//Page 1 - works fine
app.get("/employee/:stam", (req, res) => {
  const oved = req.params.stam;
  const foved = persons.find(
    (i) => i.company.location.country === oved
  );
  if (!persons) return res.status(404).send("OOPS SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
  res.json(foved);
});

//Page 2 - NOT WORKING
app.get("/employee/:stam", (req, res) => {
  const oved = req.params.stam;
  const oved2 = persons.find(
    (i) => i.age>37 === oved
  );
  if (!persons) return res.status(404).send("OOPS SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
  res.json(oved2);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("listeing....");
});
```

What is the correct way to write link for page2 (get the first employee that age>37

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same express path `"/employee/:stam"` for two middleware functions, only the first will be executed when this path matches.

It is unclear which URL patterns you want to support, but I suggest that you write only *one* middleware function that differentiates between numeric and non-numeric parameters:

```js
app.get("/employee/:stam", function(req, res) {
  if (isNaN(req.params.stam)) { // non-numeric parameter
    // Page 1
  } else { // numeric parameter
    var stamAsNumber = Number(req.params.stam);
    // Page 2
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In [RESTful](https://apiguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_and_publish/use_RESTful_urls.html) urls  there are two main concepts that are important to you here:

**Resource Identifiers** and **Query Parameters**.

In short, a **Resource Identifier** is used to locate a resource, in your case a specific employee record from a database. That would be the employee id or whatever value you use to uniquely identify each employee. In express you would typically pass that as a `req.param` like so:

```html
<a href="/employee/12345">oved 2</a>
```

```js
app.get("/employee/:id", (req, res) => {
   const {id} = req.params;
   //... find employee by employee.id == id
});
```

However, both of your values of `37` and `Holland` are not Resource Identifiers, they are Query Parameters so I would probably suggest you don't pass them as `req.params` parameters and instead use Query Parameters.

In **Query Parameters**, you pass 0 or more filters that are used to query your database and only fetch results matching conditions in your filters. These are passed in the `req.query` parameters. In your case that might look like:

```html
<a href="/employee?country=Holland">oved 1</a>
<a href="/employee?age=37">oved 2</a>
<a href="/employee?country=Holland&age=37">oved 3</a>
```

```js
app.get("/employee", (req, res) => {
   const {country, age} = req.query;
   //... find employee by employee.location.country == country and/or employee.age == age
});
```

The answer provided by [@Heiko Theißen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16462950/heiko-thei%c3%9fen) is good advice and definitely an option.

As an aside, in express you can think of the request as just falling from top to bottom in your route handler middlewares trying to make a match until it either is returned as a response, throw an error or passed to the next middleware with the `next()` function. Therefore if your first route handler had passed `next` as the third parameter to the callback you could have used that to pass the request to your second version of `app.get("/employee/:stam"`. For example:

```js
app.get("/employee/:stam", (req, res, next) => {
   if(isNaN(req.params.stam)){ //< page 1 stuff
      const oved = req.params.stam;
      const foved = persons.find(
         (i) => i.company.location.country === oved
      );
      if (!persons) return res.status(404).send("OOPS SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
      res.json(foved);
   }else{ 
      next(); //< go to page 2 stuff
   }
});
```

**Note**: this is just to help explain and is not a good design option.